# How to read and write values to OPC UA server using python restful api?

Tags: python, api, rest, opc-ua, opc

I have created the python web service using rest api and build UI using pyside6. when i give post values from UI using rest api it should be able to then write/post to opcua server.How can i achieve this or what will be the approach.

Need with code example. Big thank you.
here i have to make changes in api service written in python ->

```
@requires_login
def post_car_setting(api_key, id: str, car_settings_schema: CarSettingsSchema, login=None) -> Response:
    carModel:CarModel=CarModel.fetch_by_id(id)
    if carModel is not None:
        car_settings = CarSettingsModel.from_schema(car_settings_schema)
        carModel.car_settings=car_settings
        carModel.modified_by=login
        carModel.modified_on=datetime.now()
        carModel.update()
        ##opcua call hook
        return Response(body=carModel.car_settings).send_response()
    else:
        return Response(False,ErrorCodes.NOT_FOUND)
```

this code says that it save my car settings such as speed as 30 to local schema.in my UI app which is written in python+qml im using post method to save setting.i have to save car speed to opcua server from api service (in above code snippets). how the code/ logic is going to be.

Comment: If you need urgent work to be done hire a dev. This Q/A site is to build a database of useful answers to the community. Please provide enough details to make your problem explicit.

Answer (score 3):

I´m not sure if you want to make a OPC UA Server (with a UI) or you want to make an OPC UA Client that connect to an existing server.

For both solutions there are examples:

[Write an variable server-side](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/bb03fed7eaef4eedb43bc078b72e740c7982e653/examples/server-minimal.py#L43)

[Write an variable client-side](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/bb03fed7eaef4eedb43bc078b72e740c7982e653/examples/client-minimal.py#L26)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [asyncua](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio) to access the server data. If you need a example how access the server use [this](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/client-minimal.py) as starting point. For the integration I can't help you without knowing which framework you are using.

Comment: due word limitation i have updated the question. please refer it. im also using yaml file to read the server tags.